# Extracting highlighted content in pdf automatically as images

Tags: pdf, image-processing

I have a pdf file in which some text and images are highlighted using highlight text(U) tool. Is there a way to automatically extract all the highlighted content as separate images and save it to a folder? I dont want readable text. I just want all the highlighted content as images. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use PDF library to iterate through all the Annotation objects and their properties to see which ones are using a highlight annotation.  Once you have found the highlight annotation you can then extract the position and size (bounding box) of the annotation.

Once you have a list of the annotation bounding boxes you will need to render the PDF file to an image format such as PNG/JPEG/TIFF so that you can extract / clip the rendered image of the annotation text you want.  You could use GDI+ or something like LibTIFF

There are various PDF libraries that could do this including

http://www.quickpdflibrary.com  (I consult for QuickPDF) or 
http://www.itextpdf.com

Here is a C# function based on Quick PDF Library that does what you need.

```
    private void ExtractAnnots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dpi = 300;
        Rectangle r;
        List<Rectangle> annotList = new List<Rectangle>();

        QP.LoadFromFile("samplefile.pdf", "");

        for (int p = 1; p <= QP.PageCount(); p++)
        {
            QP.SelectPage(p);  // Select the current page.
            QP.SetOrigin(1);   // Set origin to top left.

            annotList.Clear();

            for (int i = 1; i <= QP.AnnotationCount(); i++)
            {
                if (QP.GetAnnotStrProperty(i, 101) == "Highlight")
                {
                    r = new Rectangle((int)(QP.GetAnnotDblProperty(i, 105) * dpi / 72.0),  // x
                                      (int)(QP.GetAnnotDblProperty(i, 106) * dpi / 72.0),  // y
                                      (int)(QP.GetAnnotDblProperty(i, 107) * dpi / 72.0),  // w
                                      (int)(QP.GetAnnotDblProperty(i, 108) * dpi / 72.0)); // h

                    annotList.Add(r); // Add the bounding box to the annotation list for this page.

                    string s = String.Format("page={0}: x={1} y={2} w={3} h={4}\n", p, r.X, r.Y, r.Width, r.Height);
                    OutputTxt.AppendText(s);
                }
            }

            // Now we have a list of annotations for the current page.
            // Delete the annotations from the PDF in memory so we don't render them.

            for (int i = QP.AnnotationCount(); i >= 0;  i--)   
                QP.DeleteAnnotation(i);

            QP.RenderPageToFile(dpi, p, 0, "page.bmp");   // 300 dpi, 0=bmp
            Bitmap bmp = Image.FromFile("page.bmp") as Bitmap; 

            for (int i=0;i<annotList.Count;i++)
            {
                Bitmap cropped = bmp.Clone(annotList[i], bmp.PixelFormat);

                string filename = String.Format("annot_p{0}_{1}.bmp", p, i+1);
                cropped.Save(filename);
            }

            bmp.Dispose();
        }

        QP.RemoveDocument(QP.SelectedDocument());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, Can you just help me with the code? I want to go with either quickpdflibrary or itextpdf.

Comment: I have updated the original post with some code that works well in C# using Quick PDF Library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want each piece of text as a separate highlight or all the higlhights on a separate pane?

Comment: I want each piece of highlighted content as separate images.